# Angular6 (click) not passing event in case of div

Tags: angular

I was following :
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/59/Angular-4-Event-Binding

[image]

and my code is as below: I am using div at place of button:

```
<div (click)="updateSelectedLanguage($event)">
    <!-- More items -->
</div>
```

And :

```
  updateSelectedLanguage(event : any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

However, event is always undefined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `$event` reserved variable in the template, in that case, passes to the controller the event information about the click (position, target, etc.). However, you are passing in the template `item`, but it seems to be undefined. So in the controller you see `undefined`. Then you should pass something defined, like:

```
<div (click)="updateSelectedLanguage('es')">
    <!-- More items -->
</div>
<div (click)="updateSelectedLanguage('en')">
    <!-- More items -->
</div>
```

Or maybe you want to get the event's target (the div that was clicked)?

```
<div (click)="updateSelectedLanguage($event)">
    <!-- More items -->
</div>

updateSelectedLanguage(event : any) {
   console.log(event.target);
}
```

**Edit** due author's main post edition:

Then something else is wrong with your code. Here you have an example that ilustrates that your snippet is working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxmcsh

Comment: Please check my updated question. sorry for the confusion. I had already passed $event. had changed that for trial error.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, its tag is a button, so when you pass $event, you pass the button click event. buttons have predefined structures, which will be part of that event.

In your case, you have it attached to a div, divs don't have predefined structures, you have to give it to them with data, maybe ngModel or ngForm structures.

Answer (score -1):

What is **item** that you pass? Is it some variable that you need to pass. If you want to pass event argument in your function on click in the HTML you need to pass $event.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the miscommunication. please check updated question. $event is not working and that was concern at first place. item was misplaced here.